# javascript SyntaxError: Identifier 'img' has already been declared

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take a picture from local notebook camera with this code:

```
function takePhoto(img)
{ 
  const img = img || document.querySelector('img');

  imageCapture.takePhoto()
  .then(blob => {
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.src = url;
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); 
  })
  .catch(error);
};

takePhoto();
```

but getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'img' has already been declared
```

I checked, there is no any declaration of `img` in the code above (also tried to rename it to something like `image_local`, no use). Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: The parameter name `img` is essentially a declaration. Also note that the call to the function at the end of the posted code does not pass an argument anyway.

Comment: `function takePhoto(img)` <- first declaration of `img`; `const img` <- second declaration of `img`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

`const img = img || document.querySelector('img');`

to:

`img = img || document.querySelector('img');`

**Explanation:**

Your function definition includes the `img` parameter

`function takePhoto(img)`

This is effectively declaring a variable called `img` to be used within the function with whatever value was passed in at the time of the function call. You are then trying to redeclare the `img` variable as a constant inside the function:

`const img ...`

You can't do this, as noted by the SyntaxError that you received.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed. I have updated the answer to include a brief explanation. Thank you for the push towards appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a constant with the same name as an existing variable. In this case, img in your function parameters. Call one of the two something different.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you mentioned

> "there is no any declaration of img in the code above"

...in fact there are two declarations (as per the error message):

1)

```
function takePhoto(img)
```

This effectively declares the variable, because it brings it into the scope of the function with that name.

2)

```
const img
```

Here you attempt to declare the same variable again.

You can have one declaration of the same variable, at most. Changing

```
const img = img || document.querySelector('img');
```

to

```
img = img || document.querySelector('img');`
```

will fix it, as it no longer attempts to re-declare the variable, it now merely (potentially) changes its value.